# VSCode Terminal font changed

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

All of a sudden the font of my VSCode Terminal changed, does anyone know the solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: it is because by default `terminal` uses `editor.fontFamily` it seems you changed your editor font to a non monospace font

Comment: Did you solve this? Same thing happened to me today.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating the `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` in `settings.json`.

Details: https://vscode.one/terminal-font-size/

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> and type `Reload Window`